# Reproject numpy array based on bbox (extent)

Tags: python, coordinate-system, extents, numpy

I have a NumPy array image which is basically NDVI values.
The image looks like this:

[image]

I know the bbox coordinates of this image (e.g (bbox_coords_wgs84=[minx, miny, maxx, maxy]))

I'm looking for python functions to use in order to reproject easily this image based on the bbox coordinates. I sawnrasterio has functions but it looks a bit complicated for the situation I have already the bbox.

Comment: Maybe look into using `rasterio.transform.from_bounds` https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.from_bounds